# I want to create List from Another List Like this(flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

*this is my default List*

```
List dataset = [{"label":"m1","backgroundColor":"#2320df","data":[128, 123 ,107]},{"label":"m2","backgroundColor":"#11d414","data":[34,34,34]}];
```

*wanted result*

```
List list = [[128,34],[132,34],[107,34]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do so like:

```
 List dataset = [
    {
      "label": "m1",
      "backgroundColor": "#2320df",
      "data": [128, 123, 107]
    },
    {
      "label": "m2",
      "backgroundColor": "#11d414",
      "data": [34, 34, 34]
    }
  ];
  List resultList = [];
  List l1 = dataset[0]['data'];
  List l2 = dataset[1]['data'];
  for (int i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
    resultList.add([l1[i], l2[i]]);
  }
  print(resultList);
```

output:

```
[[128, 34], [123, 34], [107, 34]]
```

edit:

The easies solution would be to aggregate the lists as a Matrix and apply `transport` on them,
this package helps you to do so:

https://pub.dev/packages/matrix2d

the code would look like this:

```
List dataset = [
      {
        "label": "m1",
        "backgroundColor": "#2320df",
        "data": [128, 123, 107]
      },
      {
        "label": "m2",
        "backgroundColor": "#11d414",
        "data": [34, 34, 34]
      }
    ];
    List resultList = [];
    List tempList = [];
    for (Map item in dataset) {
      tempList.add(item['data']);
    }
    resultList = tempList.transpose;
    print(resultList);
```

output:

```
[[128, 34], [123, 34], [107, 34]]
```

Comment: list is completely dynamic, so may be it should have more than twoaray

Comment: are the number of items in "data" 3 always or also dynamic ?

Comment: item count in "data" are also dynamic

Comment: add this line to the top of the file:

`import 'package:matrix2d/matrix2d.dart';`

Comment: you're welcome. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: matrix2d not support double value !!! any solution ??